# "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" error occurred when creating pod in istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio

K8S version：1.14.2

Istio version：1.12.4

OS：CentOS 7

Following this guide, but error occurred.

https://istio.io/docs/examples/bookinfo/

```
$ kubectl describe rs details-v1-c5b5f496d
....
Events:
  Type     Reason        Age                   From                   Message
  ----     ------        ----                  ----                   -------
  Warning  FailedCreate  8m38s (x18 over 19m)  replicaset-controller  Error creating: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "sidecar-injector.istio.io": Post https://istio-sidecar-injector.istio-system.svc:443/inject?timeout=30s: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

```
[root@centos-10-90-152-38 k8s]# kubectl get mutatingwebhookconfiguration istio-sidecar-injector -o yaml -o jsonpath='{.webhooks[0].clientConfig.caBundle}' | md5sum
7a67a48a97a2c079958225147a65d7cb  -
[root@centos-10-90-152-38 k8s]# kubectl -n istio-system get secret istio.istio-sidecar-injector-service-account -o jsonpath='{.data.root-cert\.pem}' | md5sum
7a67a48a97a2c079958225147a65d7cb  -
```

Comment: Could this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

From istio.io:

"x509: certificate signed by unknown authority related errors are typically caused by an empty caBundle in the webhook configuration."

Troubleshooting tips are available in the link below:

[istio.io: creating-configuration-fails-with-x509-certificate-errors](https://istio.io/docs/ops/setup/validation/#creating-configuration-fails-with-x509-certificate-errors)

Comment: Link has moved to [Creating configuration fails with x509 certificate errors](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/common-problems/validation/#creating-configuration-fails-with-x509-certificate-errors)